# Python PLY Lex ambiguity

Tags: python, lex, ambiguity, ply

I have a problem with ambiguity on tokens level.

The problem looks like this.
My code looks like this so token t_UN1 has higher precedence.

```
t_ignore = ' \t\v\r' # whitespace 

....

def t_UN1(t): #NS_
    r'NS\_'
    return t
def t_IDENTIFIER(t):
    r'[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*'
    return t

....
```

I would like to achieve that eg. string: NS_XYZ is identified as "IDENTIFIER"
and single NS_ surrounded by white spaces is identified as "UN_1".

How shall I handle that ? Currently string NS_XYZ is simply splited into two tokens UN1 and IDENTIFIER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to get 'single NS_ surrounded by white spaces', you can add the white space character class into your token string:

```
def t_UN1(t): #NS_
    r'\s+NS\_\s+'
    return t
```

Side note: for PLY questions, the [ply-hack google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/ply-hack) is a good place to ask PLY-related questions.

Comment: ply-hack tells me I don't have permission to post *despite having joined* the group. I have tried both web interface and email.